# How to add TF on a object whose coordinate is already detected by PCL

Tags: ros, c++, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The coordinate of the object is already detected by PCL. For this purpose, I am using a Kinect v2 camera. I have written that code in C++ and I am working in ROS platform. Now I want to add TF on the object detected by the Kinect using PCL library.

Extra notes: My objective is to grab a moving object on a conveyor belt by a robot.

I am really stuck at this moment. Any ideas would be a great help for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275266/how-to-add-tf-on-a-object-whose-coordinate-is-already-detected-by-pcl/) by [alone2](https://answers.ros.org/users/32447/alone2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to write transformation broadcaster for that. Have a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29) on how to do it.

You simply create tf broadcaster publishing transformation from one frame (e.g. pointcloud frame) to another (e.g. object_frame).

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alone2](https://answers.ros.org/users/32447/alone2/) on 2017-11-08**:
TF of Kinect camera will also act as a TF for the object? I am confused about the alignment of the Robot end effector and the object. I want to keep them face to face wherever I will put the object.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-08**:
No, those two will be different tf frames. You will probably have some kind of transformation between those two frames (using tf broadcaster). Assuming you calculate position of your object relatively to your kinetic frame.